# Using browserify on a static website

Tags: git, browserify, github-pages

I would like to host a static website on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), and be able to use Browserify in my scripts for loading modules.

What is the simplest way to do this? I had thought of setting a git pre-commit hook that bundles the scripts before each commit, but I will need to configure this hook every time I clone the repo...

Another method, I think, is by using a task manager such as Grunt or Gulp, but isn't this a little bit too much? I want my project to stay as simple as possible.

Thanks for your answers :)